# How can I make a png's Alpha contain undetectable colours?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, png, image-format

Okay, I'll try to make a long story short. I use PS elements 8 (yeah I know that barely counts a PS).

I make textures for a video game mod, and I came across a problem. To help explain I quickly put together this little gallery because I can't explain my problem in words, it would take 5-6 paragraphs. https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2SA0.jpg

The last image is the actual Yellow eye texture that has the weird transparency. The transparent part has no colour when you use the eyedropper as you would expect.

Interestingly if I open the Yellow eye image in PS and save it as a png it removes almost all of the hidden pixels. All that remains is a rectangle around the eye itself. Any help on how to save pngs in the same way that is used here would be invaluable to me. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that the yellow eye texture is used without alpha/transparency, and merely replaces the normal eye texture.

Another part of the problem is that Photoshop Elements doesn't let you adjust channels. The transparent areas in textures is usually due to an "alpha channel", which is like a mask for the entire image, but is stored as a fourth channel. (Masks let you conceal parts of an image without actually erasing the image data.) You may need a different image editor, or perhaps a utility that lets you extract the alpha channel and also merge it back in to a non-alpha RGB image.

Otherwise, you might want to create a different yellow eye texture that has green skin.